# What are best practices for API error response handling?

Tags: django, flutter, api

It is best practice to handle such API errors by `try` and `catch` or the API response suppose to be like Google, Facebook and Microsoft API call

[image]

[Google API call example](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v1/errors)

[Facebook API call example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/error-handling/)

[Microsoft API call example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors)

Comment: There are no best practices; see https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164.  Every case should be considered on its own merits.  There are "common" ways to do things, and ways to do things that are "good" most of the time (for some meaning of "good").  But the idea of a "best practice" is an illusion.  At least in IT and programming.  So-called "best practice" is just opinion, so you are actually asking for opinions.  That is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, there isn't such a thing as a standard API, so there also isn't a best practice as such either. If you are dealing with multiple APIs within your app, you'll end up having at least a handful of variations in what you check for and how you adapt.

Depending on how terminal the failure is, and where it happens in their processing stack, the HTTP status may be set, and you may also get an HTML, JSON or XML body with more detail (no matter what you thought you might get).

APIs also fail randomly with transient errors, so for your code to work reliably, you probably need a retry loop somewhere.

They also throttle, so some kind of detect/backoff/retry handler would help (details vary per API, as ever).

Psuedocode:

```
retry loop {
   request
   check connection (network errors)
   check HTTP status code
   check body
   parse body if valid and extract errors
   if terminal failure exit (authentication/authorisation etc)
   if throttling backoff
}
```